# Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'forEach') when i use nodejs

Tags: mysql, node.js, express

[image]

| header 1 | header 2 |
| --- | --- |
| cell 1 | cell 2 |
| cell 3 | cell 4 |

```
app.post('/success', function (req, res) {

    var con = mysql.createConnection({
        host: "localhost",
        user: "root",
        password: "",
        database: 'project'
    })
    const id = 1;
    con.query("SELECT * FROM orders WHERE id = ${id}", (err, result) => {
        username = req.session.username
        res.render('pages/success', { result: result, username: username });
        //res.send("hello")
    })
})
```

display payment receipt

Comment: You should check the `err` result -- that would have told you that there was a syntax error in the query and you might have figured out the problem on your own.

Answer (score 0):

The use of template literal is wrong, please correct following line

```
 con.query("SELECT * FROM orders WHERE id = ${id}", (err, result) => {
```

to

```
 con.query(`SELECT * FROM orders WHERE id = ${id}`, (err, result) => {
```

we are updating Quotation-mark(") to literals(`). for more about [template-literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals)

Comment: It would be better to recommend a parametrized query to prevent SQL injection.